# Adding a persistent static route to a Mac

Tags: macos, routes

I need to add a persistent static route on my Mac. There are out there several tutorials that suggest the same commands.

First, I tried a temporary route as suggested.

```
route -n add -net 10.254.5.234/32 192.168.67.8
```

And the route works as expected.

So, as suggested in all the tutorials, I moved to the persistent route.

```
networksetup -setadditionalroutes "Wi-Fi" 10.254.5.234 255.255.255.255 192.168.67.8
```

However, the route seems not to work even if it has been added.

```
networksetup -getadditionalroutes Wi-Fi
10.254.5.234 255.255.255.255 192.168.67.8
```

Am I missing something here?